# calculate the volume formed by rotation of a given region

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration

I have a question in elementary differential calculus:

Let $S$ be a region given by

$$S=\{(x,y): 0\leq x\leq 1,\ \ 3^x-x-1\leq y\leq x\}$$

then define $V$ the solid obtained by rotating $S$ around $$y=x$$, how to calculate the volume of $V$? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: We can show by simple calculus the form of $S$, so take the line $y=x$ around which $S$ rotates for a new abscissa $z$, we find that the volume of $V$ could be rewritten as the integral of $\pi^2r(z)$ from $z=0$ to $z=\sqrt{2}$, where $r(z)$ is the instance of the point $(z,0)$ and $(z, w(z))$ with $w(z)$ is the new abscissa of the curve $y=3^x-x-1$. But it is difficult to get the explicit expression of $r(z)$....

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the coordinate system 45 degrees counter-clockwise to obtain a function that can be rotated about the $x$ axis.

This can be done by applying the transformation matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}4\right) & -\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}4\right)\\
\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}4\right) & \cos\left(-\frac{\pi}4\right)
\end{bmatrix} = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
to a paramterization of $3^x-x-1$
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
t\\
-3^t-t-1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
3^t-1\\
3^t-2t-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and converting to new coordinates by solving
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} = 
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
3^t-1\\
3^t-2t-1
\end{bmatrix}$$
So, $x = \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(3^t-1\right) \implies t=\log_3\left(\sqrt{2}x+1\right)$

Plugging this into $3^t-2t-1$ gives the new function $$y=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(3^{\log_3(\sqrt2x+1)} - 2\log_3(\sqrt2x+1)-1\right)=x-\sqrt2\log_3\left(\sqrt2x+1\right)$$

$y=x$ has now been transformed to $y=0$ and the integration limits $0$ and $1$ to $0$ and $\sqrt2$ respectively.

Now calculate the volume using the normal method for rotations about the x axis.

$$V = \pi\int_0^{\sqrt2}y^2\;\text{d}x = \pi\int_0^{\sqrt2}\left(x-\sqrt2\log_3\left(\sqrt2x+1\right)\right)^2\;\text{d}x$$

which can be solved using standard integration methods.

The answer according to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+sqrt%282%29+pi%2a%28x-sqrt%282%29%2alog%28sqrt%282%29x%2B1%29%2Flog%283%29%29%5E2) is $\approx 0.0860724$.